# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined discord bot

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord, send

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
    client.channels.get(config.logChannel).send(embed)
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.client.once (/home/fynn/DiscordTickets/server.js:119:43)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Client.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at WebSocketConnection.triggerReady (/home/fynn/DiscordTickets/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:128:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.checkIfReady (/home/fynn/DiscordTickets/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:144:61)
    at ReadyHandler.handle (/home/fynn/DiscordTickets/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/Ready.js:80:8)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/fynn/DiscordTickets/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/fynn/DiscordTickets/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/fynn/DiscordTickets/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
```

public source code: https://github.com/eartharoid/DiscordTickets

````
      .setAuthor(`${client.user.username} / Ticket Log`, client.user.avatarURL)
      .setColor("#2ECC71")
      .setDescription(":white_check_mark: **Started succesfully**")
      .setFooter(`DiscordTickets by Eartharoid`);
    client.channels.get(config.logChannel).send(embed)
  } else {
    client.channels.get(config.logChannel).send(":white_check_mark: **Started succesfully**")
  } ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are you sure the bot has access to that channel?**
This is because if the client is not able to see the channel, it will give you an undefined back

**Are you sure the ID in of the channel in your config is a String?**
discord.js needs a [Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake) in the `ChannelManager.get()` method

**Maybe try this instead of `.get()`**

```
client.channels.fetch(config.logChannel)
```

This is a method that ships with the ChannelManager, that as far as I know does basicly the exact same as `.get()` method on a Discord Collection.

Sorry for my not so good english, tried my best to answer your questions with some explanations!